# Nested query in MySQL using select statement

Tags: mysql, nested-select

I am having trouble with the activity I have in MySQL.

Below are the tables of my employee database, and I want to show the **dept_name** column from the department table, **first_name** and **last_name** from the employee table, and the **title_name** from the title table.

[ER diagram for employee database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiQvo.png)

The instruction is to query it using a select statement. If anyone knows how to do it, please help me :< thank you so much.

Comment: Do not post image! Pls write it, provide with sample data and expected output. Also, what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JOIN or write as below

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, d.dept_name, t.title_name
FROM employee e, department d, title t, emp_dept ed, emp_title et
WHERE 
e.emp_no = ed.emp_no AND ed.dept_no = d.dept_no
AND e.emp_no = et.emp_no AND et.title_no = t.title_no
```